# Asignar un dato a un campo, según el contenido de otro campo

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. En la actualidad tengo este código y deseo hacerle una modificación.

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registros/Validados", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados")]
    public List<TemLlantasSalidasRegistros> GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados(int Anho, int Mes, 
        string? Obra, string? Almacen) 
    {
        var t = GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(Anho, Mes);
        var q = from a in t
                where
                (
                    (
                        Obra == null
                        ||
                        Obra == ""
                        ||
                        Obra == a.Obra
                    )
                    &&
                    (
                        Almacen == null
                        ||
                        Almacen == ""
                        ||
                        Almacen == a.nom_bodega
                    )
                )
                //join con la tabla obtenida en GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros(Anho, Mes) on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = a.fecha,
                    Equipo = a.equipo,
                    Salida = a.numero,
                    Bodega = a.bodega,
                    Cantidad = a.cantidad
                }
                equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = b1.Fecha,
                    Equipo = b1.Equipo,
                    Salida = b1.Salida,
                    Bodega = b1.Bodega,
                    //2024-01-31: Como aqui tenemos la cantidad de llantas desmontadas y montadas, se debe dividir por dos para
                    //que coincida con las salidas de llantas. 
                    Cantidad = b1.Cantidad / 2
                }
                into GrupoB
                //esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby
                    a.Obra,
                    a.equipo,
                    a.fecha
                select new TemLlantasSalidasRegistros
                {
                    equipo = a.equipo,
                    bodega = a.bodega,
                    nom_bodega = a.nom_bodega,
                    cod_familia = a.cod_familia,
                    familia = a.familia,
                    fecha = a.fecha,
                    codigo = a.codigo,
                    descripcion = a.descripcion,
                    tipo_salida = a.tipo_salida,
                    tipo = a.tipo,
                    numero = a.numero,
                    cantidad = a.cantidad,
                    costo = a.costo,
                    total_costo = a.total_costo,
                    destino = a.destino,
                    horometro = a.horometro,
                    adicional = a.adicional,
                    horometro_ingresado = a.horometro_ingresado,
                    empresa = a.empresa,
                    Obra = a.Obra,
                    //Poner la función para la operacion y la validacion para el estado.
                    Operacion = a.Operacion,
                    //2024-01-29: Definimos el estado, para identificar si ya se inserto la información
                    Estado = a == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
                };
        return q.ToList();
    }
```

El punto a modificar es este:

```
Estado = a == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
```

Como pueden notar tengo un join, el cual utilizo para validar si un dato ya esta insertado o esta pendiente. Mi deseo es modificar esta linea de la siguiente forma:

```
Estado = 
                        if (a is null)
                        {
                            return "Pendiente";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return "Insertada";
                        }
```

El primer error que me sale es:

Error   CS1525  Invalid expression term 'if'

El segundo error que me sale es:

Error   CS1513  } expected

El tercer error que me sale es:

Error   CS1002  ; expected

Puedo identificar claramente que estoy escribiendo mal la expresión, así que agradezco si me pueden indicar la forma correcta.

Comment: te di una respuesta, pero ahora que miro, si a fuera null, todo el resto del codigo daria error, porque no podria acceder a las variables que estas pidiendo... estas seguro que este codigo funciona?

Comment: Si gbianchi, el código funciona sin la validación if, sino con el ternario.

Comment: es que no pregunte eso.. si a es null, entonces Obra = a.Obra, deberia tirar error en tiempo de ejecucion, salvo que me este saltando alguna validacion de linq...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se porque queres reemplazar un ternario por algo que hace exactamente lo mismo, pero no, no podes aplicar un if a una variable así como lo escribiste.. no es lo mismo.

El ternario, hace todo en una línea, porque está hecho para eso justamente.

El if es una instrucción completa, que no se puede asignar a una variable, y el return se usa para salir de una función, no para retornar el valor de un if.

Si queres reescribirlo, es de la siguiente forma:

```
if (a is null)
{
    Estado = "Pendiente";
}
else
{
    Estado = "Insertada";
}
```

**PERO**

estás adentro de un new object, y entonces, no te queda otra que usar la forma ternaria del if.

Comment: Muy amable gbianchi por la respuesta. Mi interés nace por la siguiente situación: La condición ternario solo me permite tener dos opciones para asignarle al campo, pero si deseo tener una tercera o cuarte opción, pensé que podría utilizar el validador if como mi ayuda. Por ejemplo: if (a.obra is null) {"pendiente";} else if (a.obra == "IRRA") {"Corregir Obra";} else {"Insertar;} . Estaba evaluando si esto lo podía hacer o si es necesario hacer una función con esta estructura y luego invocarla.

Comment: podes anidar ternarios sin problemas. No soy tan experto en linq, pero capaz podes poner una funcion anonima ahi adentro? ni lo probe...

Comment: gbianchi, que interesante. Como seria la función anónima que cumple con eso?. Veo de provecho el aprender a hacerla. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes escribir una función

```
public bool GetEstado(TemLlantasSalidasRegistros a){
  if (a is null)
  {
    return "Pendiente";
  }
  return "Insertada";
}
```

Y luego en la consula Linq haces:

```
Estado = GetEstado(a)
```

O puedes usar un `switch` en la misma consulta linq

```
Estado = a switch {
  null => "pendiente",
  {obra: "IRRA"} => "Corregir Obra",
  _ => "Insertar" //el guion bajo es equivalente al "else"
}
```